# Understanding routing in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to wrap my mind around the way ASP.NET MVC implements routing.

From what is my current understanding, it seems my route string much have a "{controller}" and "{action}", otherwise it doesn't work?

How would I define the route that using a `SearchController` and `Search` action taking both `SearchKeywords` and `SearchCaseSensitive` arguments had the following URL?

```
domain/SearchKeywords/CaseSensitive
```

Even simpler, how do I map `domain` to controller `SearchController` and to `Search`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From what is my current understanding,
>   it seems my route string much have a
>   "{controller}" and "{action}",
>   otherwise it doesn't work?

Values for the controller and action tokens are required. You have 2 options for providing the values:

1) Using {controller} and {action} tokens on the URL template. e.g.:

```
routes.MapRoute(null, "{controller}/{action}");
```

2) Using default values for controller and action. e.g.:

```
routes.MapRoute(null, "some-url",
   new { controller = "Search", action = "Search" }
);
```

> How would I define the route that
>   using a SearchController and Search
>   action taking both SearchKeywords and
>   SearchCaseSensitive arguments had the
>   following URL?
>
> domain/SearchKeywords/CaseSensitive

The URL host (or domain) is not considered by the routing system, only the application relative path. You can do this:

```
routes.MapRoute(null, "{SearchKeywords}/{CaseSensitive}",
   new { controller = "Search", action = "Search" }
);
```

You can also provide defaults for SearchKeywords and CaseSensitive, if you want to make either of them optional.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `controller = "Search", action = "Search"` to the `defaults` (the last parameter).

The routing engine will use values in `defaults` to fill in for parameters that aren't in the URL.

Comment: But that has the problem that if I want to add more routing rules, this one will "eat" them up. or not?

Comment: Also, how does it interpret domain/Abc? It will think Abc is the controller while I want it to be the string to search about!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a 'domain' parameter in your route, you must put this at the top of the route registration.  The 'domain' parameter in the second anonymous object is a constraint and here is set to be a regular expression that tests to see if the domain is either of the possible domains "DefaultDomain" or "OtherDomain".

```
        routes.MapRoute("DomainRoute", "{domain}/{controller}/{action}",
                        new {domain = "DefaultDomain", controller = "Search", action = "Search"},
                        new {domain = "DefaultDomain|OtherDomain"});
```

Comment: domain is not a parameter, its your site's domain

Comment: the routing doesn't take the domain into account

Comment: running domain/myargs will not call SearchController.Search(myargs)